# Could the mutex protect the data relative to the specific pointer?

Tags: c++, qt, mutex

My Qt app uses `QMutex` and `QMutexLocker` to ensure thread-safety.

Does the mutex protect the data or scope of the function?

For example:

```
class Counter
{
public:
  Counter() { *ptr; }
  void setObject(MyClass *pr){ptr = pr;}

  void increment() { QMutexLocker locker(&mutex); //dowork for ptr; }
  void decrement() { QMutexLocker locker(&mutex); //dowork for pointer to MyClass, ptr; }

private:
  mutable QMutex mutex;
  MyClass *ptr;
};

//Thread...
Counter counter;
MyClass *mclass= new MyClass;
//setting... mclass
counter.setOjbect(mclass);

OtherClass oc;  //This `OtherClass` also works for mclass same as the value of Counter.
oc.setObject(mclass);  //Counter and OtherClass work for mclass.
 //Mutex protect mclass data?
```

The pointer to `MyClass` could be used in some other class.

Does `QMutexLocker` protect the data for `ptr` or protect only accessing function `increment` and `decrement` from the multiple calling?

How can I protect data at `ptr`?

Comment: It will protect the scope of function.

Comment: @talent_developer, and then the app couldn't protect data for the pointer using Mutext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutual exclusion is ensured for all threads using the same `QMutex` instance e.g. it protects data. So another class cannot synchronize its access to `MyClass` because it cannot access the mutex (unless you can ensure two thread do not touch the same member fields).

You should guarantee that everyone who accesses `MyClass` instance uses the same mutex instance. This can be done by:

- Moving the mutex to `MyClass` instance. This is what you most likely need.
- Use a single global pool of mutexes and use `MyClass` instance address to select a mutex for it.

The latter way is shown below:

```
const std::size_t SIZE = 47; // prime numbers work better here
statuc QMutex g_mtx[SIZE];

QMutex &get_mutex(const void *ptr)
{
    return g_mtx[std::uintptr_t(ptr) % SIZE];
}
```

To guard an instance of `MyClass` pointer to `ptr` you should use `QMutexLocker(get_mutex(ptr))`. This is useful if `MyClass` is a small object and it exists in large numbers, so keeping a separate mutex for each instance becomes a problem.

Comment: In the 'Counter' class, could the other object access `setObject` function regardless of the mutex in the current status?

Comment: @Andrew Li , If you don't lock the mutex of that class, the function could be accessed from any callings.

Comment: @Ivan ,Could the mutex lock the static member of the class?

Comment: @AndrewLi Mutex can protect any data you want, just make sure the same data is always protected by the same mutex. For static (global) data a global mutex will do, for something that is allocated during execution you should either allocated a separate mutex or use a mutex pool like in my example.

Comment: To clarify: There is no secret behind-the-scenes mechanism that ties a mutex to any particular piece of data--by itself, the mutex doesn't protect anything. What protects a particular piece of data is the agreement by every thread to lock a particular mutex before reading or writing that piece of data, thus ensuring that thread A will never read (or write) that piece of data while thread B is in the middle of writing to it.  Ideally that promise will be enforced by the structure of your code (e.g. by making sure only your function can access the data, and that your function locks the mutex).